# What's wrong with this SQL CREATE + INSERT batch?

Tags: sql, ssms, create-table

What is wrong with this SQL statement?

```
Create table JaretsSchedule
(
    ScheduleID Int Primary Key NOT NULL,
    FieldID Int NOT NULL,
    HomeTeamID Int NOT NULL,
    AwayTeamID Int NOT NULL,
    GameTime DateTime NOT NULL
);

Insert into JaretsSchedule
Values 
(1, 1, 1, 2, '2012-10-02 12:00:00'),
(1, 1, 1, 3, '2012-10-17 12:00:00'),
(1, 1, 1, 4, '2012-09-23 12:00:00'),
(1, 2, 2, 1, '2012-09-12 12:00:00'),
(1, 3, 3, 1, '2012-08-19 12:00:00'),
(1, 4, 4, 1, '2012-07-25 12:00:00'),
(2, 2, 2, 1, '2012-09-15 12:00:00'),
(2, 2, 2, 3, '2012-09-06 12:00:00'),
(2, 2, 2, 4, '2012-08-28 12:00:00'),
(2, 1, 1, 2, '2012-10-02 12:00:00'),
(2, 3, 3, 2, '2012-08-11 12:00:00'),
(2, 4, 4, 2, '2012-07-17 12:00:00'),
(3, 3, 3, 1, '2012-08-19 12:00:00'),
(3, 3, 3, 2, '2012-08-11 12:00:00'),
(3, 3, 3, 4, '2012-08-03 12:00:00'),
(3, 1, 1, 3, '2012-10-17 12:00:00'),
(3, 2, 2, 3, '2012-10-17 12:00:00'),
(3, 4, 4, 3, '2012-07-09 12:00:00'),
(4, 4, 4, 1, '2012-07-25 12:00:00'),
(4, 4, 4, 2, '2012-07-17 12:00:00'),
(4, 4, 4, 3, '2012-07-09 12:00:00'),
(4, 1, 1, 4, '2012-09-23 12:00:00'),
(4, 2, 2, 4, '2012-08-28 12:00:00'),
(4, 3, 3, 4, '2012-08-03 12:00:00');
```

With the resulting error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 8
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__JaretsSc__9C8A5B696CFE9A03'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.JaretsSchedule'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Comment: There are 4 teams, 4 fields, and 4 schedules.

Comment: The error message is literally telling you what the problem is.  You can't insert the same `ScheduleID` value more than once.  Check you insert data.

Comment: I renamed this question because SQL Server does not implement the ancient and obsolete IBM language "Sequel". Instead it implements SQL. SQL today in 2019 is nothing like how Sequel was in the 1970s.

Comment: You are using the same value for the primary key, that is the error, as specified by the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is literally telling you what the problem is.  You can't insert the same value more than once for the `ScheduleID` column, which you have defined as the primary key.  Once workaround here would be to just make this column an identity/auto increment column.  Then, don't even include a value for it when inserting.  Instead, let SQL Server handle it:

```
CREATE TABLE JaretsSchedule (
    ScheduleID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FieldID INT NOT NULL,
    HomeTeamID INT NOT NULL,
    AwayTeamID INT NOT NULL,
    GameTime DateTime NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO JaretsSchedule (FieldID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, GameTime)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2, '2012-10-02 12:00:00'),
    (1, 1, 3, '2012-10-17 12:00:00'),
    (1, 1, 4, '2012-09-23 12:00:00'),
    ...
```

Note also that I explicitly list out the columns, in order, which are the target for the insert.  This is also best practice, and avoids a situation later on wher it might not be clear to which columns the data in the `VALUES` clause corresponds.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Databases. Thanks, I'll look up how to make it an "identity/auto increment column"